# flutter FirebaseDynamicLinks doesn't catch onLink.listen when link's host differs than uriPrefix host

Tags: android, flutter, dynamic, hyperlink

it works if hosts are equal, but i can't open link when uriPrefix like 'https://testshare.host.us' and link 'https://test.host.us/library/movie/903?id=903&type=movie. onLink.listen doesn't catch the click.

Allowlist URL pattern for host https://testshare.host.us

^https://testshare.host.us/?id=[0-9]{1,10}&type=[A-Za-z]+

^https://test.host.us/.*$

and links like https://testshare.host.us/?id=903&type=song i can catch in app, but  https://test.host.us/library/movie/903?id=903&type=movie  - can't

what should i fix to open links like https://test.host.us/library/movie/903?id=903&type=movie ?

PS
both links successfully generate and on web works fine

Comment: Stop using Firebase Dynamic Links becuz it would be deprecated: https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq

Comment: I know, but as it is at the moment

Comment: did u try: ^https://test.host.us/library/movie/[0-9]{1,10}?id=[0-9]{1,10}&type=[A-Za-z]+

Comment: i have ^https://test.host.us/.*$m and all links create successfully